# C#: IComparable implementation private

Tags: c#, nunit, icomparable

I'm new to C# so this might be a really dump question: I implemented IComparable in my class and want to test it with NUnit. But the CompareTo-Method is marked as private and thus not accessible from the test.
What's the reason for this and how can I fix this?

The IComparable:

```
 
public class PersonHistoryItem : DateEntity,IComparable
    {
     ...
        int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            PersonHistoryItem phi = (PersonHistoryItem)obj;
            return this.StartDate.CompareTo(phi.StartDate);
        }
    }
```

The test:

```
 
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestPersonHistoryItem() {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2001, 2, 2);
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2010, 2, 2);
            PersonHistoryItem phi1 = new PersonHistoryItem(startDate,endDate);
```

```
        PersonHistoryItem phi2 = new PersonHistoryItem(startDate, endDate);

        Assert.IsTrue(phi1.CompareTo(phi2)==0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use implicit interface implementation:

```
public class PersonHistoryItem : DateEntity, IComparable
{
    ...
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        PersonHistoryItem phi = (PersonHistoryItem)obj;
        return this.StartDate.CompareTo(phi.StartDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They are not private, they are just [explicitly implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). Declaring your variables as `IComparable` should solve the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestPersonHistoryItem() {
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2001, 2, 2);
    DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2010, 2, 2);
    IComparable phi1 = new PersonHistoryItem(startDate,endDate);

    IComparable phi2 = new PersonHistoryItem(startDate, endDate);

    Assert.IsTrue(phi1.CompareTo(phi2)==0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't declare my variables as IComparable there. So according to your answer the other option would be to implement them implicitly, I guess. How would I do that?

Comment: You can also just cast them in your assert statement: `Assert.IsTrue(((IComparable)phi1).CompareTo((IComparable)phi2));`

Answer (score 1):

```
var p1 = (IComparable)phi1;
var p2 = (IComparable)phi2;

Assert.IsTrue(p1.CompareTo(p2) == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# an interface does not define accessors, so you can make your `CompareTo` method public and change the explicit interface implementation from:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
```

To:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach uses explicit interface implementation. That means that the interface methods will not show up on your class unless a cast is done.
Do this:`((IComparable)phi1).CompareTo(phi2)`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you explicitly implements the CompareTo method, which only allows you to use it when you use your object as a IComparable object.

To correct the problem, specify the visibility as public and implement the CompareTo method not "explicitly" :

```
public class PersonHistoryItem : DateEntity,IComparable
{
    ...

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        PersonHistoryItem phi = (PersonHistoryItem)obj;
        return this.StartDate.CompareTo(phi.StartDate);
    }
}
```